# Nil for maps as like for Lists

Tags: scala, maps

Is it possible to create `Nil` for maps?

I mean somethin similar to that:

```
List() match {
    case Nil => true
}
```

but with map:

```
Map() match {
    case NilMap => true
}
```

I tried to implement it, but I'm stuck:

```
object NilMap extends Map[Nothing, Nothin] {
    def unapply[K,V](map: Map[K,V]): Option[Map[K,V]] = 
       if(map.isEmpty) Some(map) else None

}
```

but id doesn't compile...

Comment: Do you only want it for empty maps?, what is wrong with just doing an simple `if`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is called a **Boolean extractor**.

```
object NilMap {
  def unapply(map: Map[_, _]): Boolean =
    map.isEmpty
}

Map.empty[String, Int] match { case NilMap() => true; case _ => false } // true
Map("a" -> 10) match { case NilMap() => true; case _ => false } // false
```